# Getting "could not find driver" when working with Redis job in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, redis

I installed my Laravel app on Ubuntu system and already installed pdo_mysql and mysqli and all extension.

Code is working fine when I run the job without Redis driver, but not working fine when using Redis driver.

I am getting below error and it's very strange for me:

> could not find driver (SQL: insert into `failed_jobs` (`connection`, `queue`, `payload`, `exception`, `failed_at`) values (redis, default, {"type":"job","timeout":null,"tags":{},"id":"1","data":{"command":"O:26:\"App\Jobs\SapProductSyncJob\":8:{s:9:\"user_data\";a:1:{s:7:\"user_id\";i:3;}s:6:\"\u0000*\u0000job\";N;s:10:\"connection\";N;s:5:\"queue\";N;s:15:\"chainConnection\";N;s:10:\"chainQueue\";N;s:5:\"delay\";N;s:7:\"chained\";a:0:{}}","commandName":"App\Jobs\SapProductSyncJob"},"displayName":"App\Jobs\SapProductSyncJob","timeoutAt":null,"pushedAt":"1584684956.0182","job":"Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call","maxTries":null,"delay":null,"attempts":2}, PDOException: could not find driver in /home/path/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:27

Comment: Do you have Redis installed? Do you have `predis/predis` installed? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redis

Comment: Yes it's already installed

Answer (score 0):

You should download, install and run redis-server in your server: [Download Redis](https://redis.io/download)

Or alternatively you can use database as a storage for your jobs by editing `.env` file:

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

Comment: I also tried with "QUEUE_CONNECTION=database" and also installed predis/predis

Comment: `predis/predis` is for your project to use the redis-server in your server, If you are running on windows you should run `redis-server.exe` file and if you are in linux you should run and set it to run on each boot. try `apt-get install redis-server` for linux in your terminal and `systemctl enable redis-server.service` to launch it each time os boots up.